# select specific record for criteria

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm getting 2 records in the results and only want 1. This is a test database and has some incomplete records in one of the tables that, I believe, is causing the incorrect results.

There are multiple records in the `PS_ASSET_NBV_TBL`. In the future, there should only be 1 record for each asset. I'm grouping on `Months_In_Service` and due to this grouping is the reason I'm getting 2 lines instead of 1.

To correct this situation in the test database, I only want to select the record with the `RUN_ID = 'TEST'`. I added a criteria to do this (annotated below) but I'm still getting 2 records in the results. Can I do this? Do I have this in the correct place in my code?

```
SELECT 
    p.account,
    p.business_unit,
    p.deptid,
    p.asset_id,
    p.descr,
    p.in_service_dt,
    p.Months_In_Service,
    p.cost,
    p.accum_depr,
    p.net_bk_value

FROM (SELECT pant.account,
    pant.business_unit,
    pant.deptid,
    pant.asset_id,
    pant.descr,
    pa.in_service_dt,
    pb.life - pb.life_remaining as Months_In_Service,
    pant.cost,
    pant.accum_depr,
    pant.net_bk_value

  FROM 
    ps_asset_nbv_tbl pant
    inner join ps_asset pa on pa.ASSET_ID = pant.asset_id and pa.business_unit = pant.business_unit
    inner join ps_book pb on pb.ASSET_ID = pant.asset_id and pb.business_unit = pant.business_unit

  WHERE 
    pant.business_unit = 'A0056'
    and pant.book = 'PERFORM'
    and pa.asset_status ='D'
    and pant.run_id = 'TEST'      (-- only added because of the test data)

  GROUP BY
    pant.account,
    pant.business_unit,
    pant.deptid,
    pant.asset_id,
    pant.descr,
    pa.in_service_dt,
    pb.life,
    pb.life_remaining,
    pant.cost,
    pant.accum_depr,
    pant.net_bk_value,
    pant.run_id
    ) p

  GROUP BY
  p.account,
  p.business_unit,
  p.deptid,
  p.asset_id,
  p.descr,
  p.in_service_dt,
  p.Months_In_Service,
  p.cost,
  p.accum_depr,
  p.net_bk_value
```

***PS_ASSET_NBV_TBL***

```
A0056   000000000003    PERFORM 0   E520GM  2   150300

A0056   000000000003    PERFORM 0   E520GM  TEST    150300

A0056   000000000003    PERFORM 0   E520GM  1   150300
```

***RESULTS***

```
150300  A0056       000000000003    Test    01-JAN-14   3   10000   333.34  9666.66

150300  A0056       000000000003    Test    01-JAN-14   4   10000   333.34  9666.66
```

Comment: HOw should we know?  You don't show any sample input or result data.

Comment: why would you `group by` your inner query if you don't use any row limitations?

Comment: I've added the table taht is causing the issue and the results that I'm currently getting.  Thanks for the help

Comment: T.S...........I'm new to sql and and working off some examples of other queries that are working.  Can you explain your question a little more.  Thanks..

Comment: @Shaves Could you please add column headers to PS_ASSET_NBV_TBL and RESULTS?

Comment: @Shaves If either `ps_asset` or `ps_book` has more than one row for a given ASSET_ID-BUSINESS_UNIT combination (if the PK includes for those tables includes other columns), then you will get duplicate rows in the result.
You can check for duplicate rows in `ps_asset` and `ps_book`, by:
`SELECT asset_id, business_unit, count(*)
FROM ps_asset --or ps_book
--WHERE business_unit = 'A0056' --if you want to check only for this business_unit
GROUP BY asset_id, business_unit
HAVING count(*) > 1;`

Comment: @Jospeh B.......Thanks. There are multiple rows in the PS_ASSET table. The subquery rolls them in to 1 record for business_unit and asset_id. There are also mupltiple records for the business_unit and asset_id in the PS_ASSET_NBV_TBL.  I only wanted to use the row with 'TEST' in the 6th column and thought by adding a criteria of  "and pant.run_id = 'TEST'" would only use that row when joinging to that table.  I thought by adding that criteria would result in 1 row in the results.  Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

The ps_asset table has more than one row matching on both asset_id and business_unit from the single row you are selecting from the ps_asset_nbv_tbl.

This is easy to spot because the results show two different values in the in_service_dt field.

You can see it for yourself with this select:

```
select * from ps_asset where asset_id = 0 and business_unit = 'A0056';
```

If you can decide which row in that table is more important you can use a MAX() or a MIN() on the value in your select or you add more criteria to exclude the unwanted row from ps_asset.

Comment: Bob.........thanks......I think the issue is in the DeptID field.  One line has a value and one is blank / empty.  This is a test database with a lot of 'bad' data.